# C# Packet Send to Game Client

Tags: c#, winsock, send, packet

I want to send packets to the game like WPE but use my specific packet and my own interfaces

so i try send packet example : Byte[] data = { 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8D, 0x45, 0x06, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x1B, 0x82, 0x14, 0x7F, 0x34, 0xD3, 0x59, 0xB5, 0xF3, 0x7F, 0xD9, 0x63, 0x4F, 0x8F, 0x5C, 0x1B, 0x19, 0x13, 0xCE, 0x2E, 0x05, 0x55, 0xE7 };

I tried to send a packet but in the game, nothing happened, so I tried to sniff my connection using wireshark or another it's correct the same result was sent like using WPE but in the game client nothing happened.

Does anyone know why?
Does anyone have a source packet sending using C#?

```
public static void Connect(String server, String message)
{
    try
    {
        // Create a TcpClient.
        // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
        // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
        // combination.
        Int32 port = 1818;
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

        // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
        Byte[] data = { 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8D, 0x45, 0x06, 0x00, 0x66, 0x41, 0x00, 0x94, 0xC6, 0xF1, 0xB9, 0xF2, 0x67, 0xBD, 0x02, 0x00, 0x29, 0x3A, 0x2D, 0x36, 0xDE, 0x1B, 0xB6, 0x94, 0xE8, 0x97, 0x19, 0xB2 };

        // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
        //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

        // Receive the TcpServer.response.

        // Buffer to store the response bytes.
        data = new Byte[256];

        // String to store the response ASCII representation.
        String responseData = String.Empty;

        // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

        // Close everything.
        stream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what WPE is?

Comment: winsock packet editor

Comment: I'm kinda confused, is that the client or server code? Gonna assume it's the client code.
I'm not sure about that network stream, maybe you need to flush it to send the bytes?

Comment: C# Application -> To Game Client (.exe) -> To Server Game maybe like remote control or modifying sending packet of the game

Comment: Let me guess, you're trying to modify a game client's packets so you can cheat. Do you really think the people who run the game's server haven't thought of that? Do you really think they're not smart enough to ignore your cheat packets?

Comment: wrong, did you know ragnarok ? open kore? i just want make smilliar app like thats for BOT or Auto Hunting, im already test one by one packet like move use potion skill attack monster etc its working (if using WPE) so i want try build my own for my self, its is mistake?